# Confusion between Google MyMaps and Google Maps embed

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am having some trouble trying to understand the differences between Google MyMaps and Google Maps. Initially I thought they were the same, but it seems they are not.

When exporting a map using Google Maps, the embed code usually looks like this:

```
<iframe width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=216563961194954003291.0004e71261d518c89283c&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=9.018795,-79.534344&amp;spn=0.012716,0.012832&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

When using Google MyMaps code is a lot more concise:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zsb3RNEWXFNg.kidBLcqVUy4E&amp;ll=z16shQdMW90E.kA2gzPBrtTZk&amp;z=18&amp;nl=1" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

What do I need? I would like to use Google MyMaps embed code but using the embed options provided in Google Maps.

For example:

MyMaps uses the "mid" parameter. Google Maps uses the "msid".

Is there a way I could transform the "mid" result provided in MyMaps to "msid"?

Same question with latitude and longitude parameters. Both Google Maps and MyMaps uses the "ll" parameter, but the result they generate are different.

"ll" results in Google Maps look like this: ll=9.018795,-79.534344
"ll" results in Google MyMaps look like this: z16shQdMW90E.kA2gzPBrtTZk

Is there a conversion tool I could use to translate "ll" results from MyMaps to Google Maps?

Thanks a lot for your clarification.

Johann

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the Google Maps Javscript API v3 the [google-maps-api-3] tag.